# How to prevent LaTeX (TexStudio) for overwriting the text beyond the bottom margin? (see the picture)

Tags: latex

I have a file where all the properties and needed packages are inside, the texfile looks like the following:

Does it have something to do with the margin properties? (First package in the code?
How can I prevent TexStudio to stop where the bottom end line of every page is?
Thanks a lot in advance..

```
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=2.5cm,top=3cm,bottom=2.5cm,head=33pt,foot=18pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

% \usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
% \usepackage{array} % http://ctan.org/pkg/array

\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}
\pagenumbering{Roman}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%Literatursystem
\usepackage[numbers,square]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtdin}

%Grafik-Einstellungen
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\usepackage{microtype}
%===========================================================================================
%===========================================================================================
%===========================================================================================
%==========Verwendete Packages und weitere Einstellungen
\usepackage{subcaption}  
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tabto}
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}

\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\captionsetup{justification=centering}

\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath} 
\setitemize{leftmargin=*,noitemsep}
\setenumerate{leftmargin=*,noitemsep} 
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}
\renewcommand*{\aclabelfont}[1]{{\textit{#1}\hfill}}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{listings}
\RequirePackage{scrlfile}
\ReplacePackage{scrpage2}{scrlayer-scrpage}
%\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption}

%===========================================================================================
%===========================================================================================
%===========================================================================================
%==========Spezielle Einstellungen
\usepackage[headsepline,footsepline]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\automark[section]{chapter}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{}
\renewcommand*\MakeUppercase[1]{#1}

\ihead{}
\chead{}
\ohead{\rightmark}

\ifoot{}
\cfoot[\thepage]{\thepage}
\ofoot{}


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
%contents

\DeclareNewTOC[%
type=formel,
name={Formel},%
hang=5em,%
listname={Formelverzeichnis}
]{for}

\newcommand*{\formelentry}[1]{%
    \addcontentsline{for}{formel}{\protect\numberline{\theequation} #1}}%


\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{2.5em}}
\makeatother
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@table{\@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{2.5em}}
\makeatother
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@formel{\@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{2.5em}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\setlength\bigstrutjot{3pt} 

\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace*{.1\baselineskip}}
\usepackage{notoccite}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{courier}

\lstdefinestyle{customc}{
    breaklines=true,
    language=C,
    showstringspaces=false,
    keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{blue},
    commentstyle={\color{green!40!black}},
    identifierstyle=\color{black},
}

\lstset{escapechar=@,style=customc}

% macro to select a scaled-down version of Bera Mono (for instance)
\makeatletter
\newcommand\BeraMonottfamily{%
    \def\fvm@Scale{0.6}% scales the font down
    \fontfamily{fvm}\selectfont% selects the Bera Mono font
}
\makeatother

\lstset{
    basicstyle=\BeraMonottfamily,lineskip={-6pt}, 
}
```

Text ist overwritten even after the page number [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdteJ.png)

Comment: Can you make a compilable [mre] that shows us which documentclass you are using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does Latex writes the text until it surpasses the footer and the bottom margin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68435653/why-does-latex-writes-the-text-until-it-surpasses-the-footer-and-the-bottom-marg)

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz No, none of my questions are answered.. But I fould a solution after a long internet search. Thanks a lot.
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88725/text-wrapping-a-footer-in-a-specific-latex-template
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/307473/text-running-into-footer-area
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/466264/main-text-goes-over-header